# JS importing non-existent variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint

a.js:

```
export const something = "something";
```

b:.js:

```
import { somethingElse } from './a';
```

If we try to import a non-existent variable like the code above, is there a way to get warned about this? (through linters, webpack, IDE etc)

Comment: In what environment (what context/tool) are you using this?

Comment: webpack, Atom Editor, ReactJS/React Native app (babel)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for the [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import) and its [`import/named`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/named.md) rule:

> ## import/named
>
> Verifies that all named imports are part of the set of named exports in the referenced module.
>
> Given:
>
> ```
> // ./foo.js
> export const foo = "I'm so foo"
> ```
>
> The following is considered valid:
>
> ```
> // ./bar.js
> import { foo } from './foo'
> ```
>
> ...and the following are reported:
>
> ```
> // ./baz.js
> import { notFoo } from './foo'
> ```

Details/docs: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/named.md and the [project's readme](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import).

Comment: Can you get the plugin to work with React Native? It works with ReactJS for me but not React Native (no error thrown).

Comment: I think it's due to React Native not using webpack.